# iterate 2d matrix with pointers columnwise

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix

I'm trying to write 2 functions that iterate a m*n matrix using a pointer in order to swap rows and columns element by element.The function that swaps rows has come out well when it comes to the other, i can't seem to figure it out.The output,when i try to swap column 3 and 2, for a matrix

```
     1   2  3 
     1   2  3
     1   2  3
```

is:

```
    1  3   2
    1  3   2
    1  2   3
```

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.Here is the code for both of them:

```
   void interchange_rows(int *p,int n,int r1,int r2){
     int temp;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        temp=*(p+r1*n+i);
        *(p+r1*n+i)=*(p+r2*n+i);
        *(p+r2*n+i)=temp;
    }
     }

   void interchange_columns(int *p,int n, int c1,int c2){
       int temp;
         for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
       temp=*(p+(i*n)-c1);
       *(p+(i*n)-c1)=*(p+(i*n)-c2);
       *(p+(i*n)-c2)=temp;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should plus c1 and c2 rather than minus.

```
void interchange_columns(int *p,int n, int c1,int c2){
    int temp;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        temp=*(p+(i*n)+c1);
        *(p+(i*n)+c1)=*(p+(i*n)+c2);
        *(p+(i*n)+c2)=temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: That works when i try to swap 3 and 1 but when i try to swap 3 and 2 it gives me an error

Comment: How did you initialize the matrix and how did you call the function? Paste the code please. interchange_columns((int*)a,3,2,1) works well here, a is defined as a[3][3]={{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}}

Comment: `interchange_columns(arr,dim,c1,c2)` where arr is the pointer to a dynamically allocated array, dim-is the dimension (it's a square matrix), c1 and c2 are the columns which are given by the user. There is also a precondition `if((c1<=dim) && (c2<=row) && (c1>=0) && (c2>=0))`. It works for swapping columns 1 and 2 and for 2 & 3, but it sais :"Heap corruption detected" when i try with 1 & 3.

Comment: So what's the value of the arguments when you swap 1 & 3? They should be (arr,3,0,2), and arr should be allocated as `new int[9]` or similar. By the way the if statement should be `if ((c1 < dim) && ...)`

Comment: Very revealing observation!The problem was with calling the function because if the number from the user is,for example c,i have to  call the function for c-1,as in  `interchange_columns(arr,dim,c-1)`.